# Is there a signal for QComboBox in PyQt for when editing is complete?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

In my application, it's problematic to have the `editTextChanged` signal sent after every single key press.  I'd like to get the signal when the user presses enter or changes focus.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the QComboBox in editable mode then you can use the [`editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal from QLineEdit:

```
combo = QComboBox()
combo.setEditable(True)
combo.lineEdit().editingFinished.connect(foo_slot)
```